# How do you benchmark memory consumption?

Tags: c++, c, memory, benchmarking

I would like to know if there is an efficient way to measure the actual memory consumption of a particular C data structure.

The goal being to make benchmarks based on how the memory usage changes after specific operations on those data structures.

I do not seek a way to count the number of objects in use; I do want to know exactly how big the memory usage of an object put under stress can get.

Is there a standard way to do that, either in C code, or from outside? (Some equivalent to the `time` (1) utility would be a start).

Obviously, I could track down every single pointer and do a sum of all `sizeof`s. If this is the only way, please do tell me. I wonder whether there is a simpler way. Or maybe a library to do it for me.

Comment: I did such tracing by parsing output of mtrace with perl script. mtrace is builtin malloc tracer of glibc; it can be activated by preloading a small .so library: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2593284/196561

Comment: this topic should be helpful : [benchmarks-used-to-test-a-c-and-c-allocator][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560114/benchmarks-used-to-test-a-c-and-c-allocator

Comment: "I do not seek a way to count the number of objects in use" If you know the number of objects and their size you'll know the memory consumption, exaxtly what do you mean?

Comment: Your way (sizeof) seems to be the only way to track the consumption of individual objects. There are some MS cmd line tools for measuring overall program memory but since it is all reclaimed by the OS on termination you might be able to set break points and monitor an object's memory consumption that way.

Comment: @Andreas, I think he means memory allocated on the heap by those objects.

Comment: Could you precise for which compiler/platform you want such details. C++ tooling is generally specific to a given platform.

Comment: @Matthieu I wish the solution wasn't platform-specific, but I am mostly interested in Unix-like.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to monitor the memory usage of the program on a global level you can replace `new/delete` in C++ or `malloc/free` in C with your own functions and log the memory usage.

Comment: That sounds very good, at first I didn't realise new/delete were amenable to overloading but having skimmed through, http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_new.html I believe that is a very efficient way to manage the heap.

Comment: Yes, and the technical term in this case is not overloading but replacement ;)

Comment: @John: there are two `operator new` in fact. The global `new`/`delete` can be replaced by your implementation, if you don't replace them, the compiler provide a default version. You can also overload them on a per-class basis.

Answer (score 3):

On Unix for memory consumption you can use valgrind with the tool Massif (+ any visualization tool), but I don't know if it is suited for your problem since it will give you a detailled view of all the memory consumption of your program.

Comment: I'll give it a try. I suppose you can sort the results by structure type, right?

Comment: @antoine: there is only an experimental visualization tool for Massif (contrary to Callgrind, for example).

Comment: @Thaddee: no, Massif is language agnostic (or almost). It gives you the state of the stack (function calls) for each allocation though, so you can trace in your code where they come from.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, cnicutar, on Linux you have pmap or maybe even pstat.

On MS there are myriad profiling tools for VStudio depending on your contribution to the MS machine (even free ones for cmd line use). Call me a green horn, I don't have issues with memory leaks.