# monitoring heap usage

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory

I want to monitor how much memory space is being used from HEAP during the execution of my program where C++ objects constructed and destroyed as needed.

What is the way to collect this information ?

I feel that overriding new and delete operators at global scope should be used somehow but I do not know exactly how to perform this.

any help ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you benchmark memory consumption?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157772/how-do-you-benchmark-memory-consumption)

Comment: Please search before posting. Or just look at the "related" pane as you type your question.

Comment: It would be helpful if you specify target platform and which heap exactly (default C heap or some custom heap).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a sample, here is the code I use to monitor usage of new/delete.

https://github.com/CYBORUS/cyborus-game-engine/blob/master/CGE/Memory.h
https://github.com/CYBORUS/cyborus-game-engine/blob/master/CGE/Memory.cpp

Comment: I increment the amount of memory used in operator new (overriden), but I can not decrement the amount of memory released in operator delete (overriden) since it does not have a size argument.

Any idea ?

Comment: Ooo..I get it. Your allocate and release methods manage it ! Thanks a lot. What about array versions ? Are they the same ?

Comment: Yes. It should work with arrays too. When you create an array, it just allocates a bigger block; the data is all contiguous. The difference is that it goes through and runs all the constructors or destructors.

Comment: can you please explain the reason for using canary ? is it stg related to endianness issue ?

Comment: The canary was mostly there for debugging these tools. My code is wandering into open memory. I needed a way to detect the presence of my header struct. It helped me discover a place in my code where I was allocating with calloc but releasing with delete. Buggy results

Comment: This could be a naive question, but with this code, how do I print the total heap allocated at a given time during the execution? `Heap.cpp` has a `dump` function. But I don't quite follow how exactly the total heap size could be printed.

Comment: @Unni The function `dump` indeed compiles a total in addition to displaying every individual heap's stats.